# c# linq the code that gets value from the table doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq

I just moved from `JAVA` to `C#` (just to get some experience) and I am trying to get some data from the database.

The database contains a table called `USERS` and columns `USER`(string) and `POINTS`(int)

Now I am trying to use `LINQ` data context and using one of the ways to select a table, but it doesn't work for some reason...

```
private int getUserPoints(string nickname)
{
    int points = 0;
    try {
        var p = from r in db.USERs
                  where r.USER1 == nickname
                  select r.POINTS;

        points = p.First();
    } catch  (Exception e){
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    return points;
}
```

Error thrown on `p.First();`

> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Could you help me out on how to resolve that issue? I am still learning c# and I know that I am jumping ahead a bit, however I am trying to do something fun that requires database communication.

Thanks!

Is the exception handling correct in this one?  I happy about tips on this manner.

UPDATE:
I believe I did configure it, I've created a LINQ to SQL CLASS and dragged the table into it.

then I initialized the context like this:

```
linkToSqlClassDataContext db = new linkToSqlClassDataContext(
                           Properties.Settings.Default.pointsGambleConnectionString);
```

Comment: how does it exactly doesn't work? what exception do you have?

Comment: did you configure the db for linq classes??

Comment: Post the exception text in your answer. It's best to post the *full* exception, including the call stack and inner exceptions. Which is as easy as logging the result of `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: Have you tried *debugging* the code? The debugger will stop if an exception gets thrown. Also, does the database contain data?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14262225/982149

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements at ... line 62 (points = p.First();)

Comment: @user2852371 Use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()`.

Comment: "InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements" - That is the documented behavior of `First()` when the underlying sequence contains no elements.

Comment: @S.Akbari I think this is a bad idea since I need to know if it has results or not. I don't need default values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you get this: `System.InvalidOperationException` Exception it means that you cannot call `First()` on an empty collection.

You could solve this point by using `FirstOrDefault` which will probably result in your case in the assignment of `0`  (the default value for `int`) to `points`.

I guess you need to work out why you cannot find any entries with this condition `where r.USER1 == nickname`.

As a side note it would be adviseable to use a `using` block, so that the connection gets properly closed after getting the desired values:

```
private int getUserPoints(string nickname)
{
    using (linkToSqlClassDataContext db = new linkToSqlClassDataContext(Properties.Settings.Default.pointsGambleConnectionString))
    {
        var p = from r in db.USERs
                where r.USER1 == nickname
                select r.POINTS;

        return p.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

You can use the try/catch block when calling this method:

```
int points = 0;
try 
{
    points = getUserPoints("yourname");
} 
catch  (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, helped a lot, also found the stupid problem, the nickname wasn't receiving the correct string (I am just using some more different libraries and I was sure that it was receiving the one I though) and thanks for the tips as well!

Comment: @user2852371 you are welcome. If you get an empty collection usually the filtering is the problem ;) (in my experience at least)